# can vectors be accessed as 2d array

Tags: c++, vector

We can use 1D arrays as 2D arrays by accessing them in this way:
[row * width + col]

My question is as vectors are very much same so can I access usual vector as 2d vector? For example in this way:
[row * vector.size() + col]

Comment: "can vectors be accessed as 2d array" - Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but not with `vector.size()`, as that would be the total count of the elements. You need to keep track of the *"width"* of the 2D array separately.

```
std::vector<int> v;
constexpr int width = 10;
constexpr int height = 10;
v.resize(width * height);

v[2 * width + 5] = 10; // set (y:2, x:5) to 10
```

Comment: how can I find width of vector if no width is explicitly specified?